# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function, count function

Tags: oracle, count

```
 select  officer.forename || ' ' || Officer.surname || ' is working on : ' || 
 count(crime.crime_id)  "Officers Current Crimes"

 From officer, crime
 where officer.officer_id = crime.officer_id
 order by crime.crime_id;
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error please, its something to do with the count function, thankyou in advance.

Comment: `GROUP BY officer.forename || ' ' || Officer.surname || ' is working on : '` Add this before  `ORDER BY.`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I then receive this error:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 2):

```
select  officer.forename, Officer.surname || ' is working on : ' || 
 count(crime.crime_id)  "Officers Current Crimes"
 From officer, crime
 where officer.officer_id = crime.officer_id
GROUP BY officer.forename, Officer.surname;
```

You cant use a `ORDER BY`  on non grouped column..

Comment: same error : ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression @MaheswaranRavisankar

Comment: See my edit, on order by.. you cant order with a non grouped column.